# "Il tram" e "la tranvia" sono la stessa cosa?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> Non ho potuto controllare l’ubicazione precisa di quell’osteria. Però qualcuno, in passato, m’accennava che per arrivarci bisognava prendere una **tranvia** suburbana, se non forse la cremagliera, su per il fianco della montagna.

In questo brano, il vocabolo "tranvia" ha attirato la mia attenzione perché non lo conoscevo. Mi sono chiesta subito se fosse la stessa cosa di "tram". Ho cercato questo termine in alcuni dizionari ma, con le definizioni che ho trovato, non riesco a capire se si tratta o meno di un "tram". Me lo potreste spiegare?

Per esempio, alla [voce "tranvia" del dizionario dei sinonimi e contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tranvia_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), non si trova "tram" come sinonimo e, alla [voce "tram"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tram_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)), non appare "tranvia".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prendo da [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tranvia) il significato letterale di "tranvia":

> Con il termine tranvia (o tramvia, traduzione dall'originale termine inglese TramWay), si intende l'infrastruttura di trasporto terrestre, idonea alla circolazione di tram sia per il trasporto di persone che di merci.[...]
>
> Di base le differenze tra *tranvia* e *ferrovia* sono poche; si differenziano invece profondamente per il metodo di circolazione dei convogli che, nel caso della tranvia, si svolge essenzialmente a vista (e ciò comporta che le velocità raggiunte non sono mai elevate) mentre nel caso dei convogli ferroviari richiede sistemi di sicurezza e di blocco, segnali e procedure restrittive.

Si tratta quindi di una rete di trasporto locale (a livello di comune o provincia) a via guidata (di solito su binari) in cui si procede lentamente. Al giorno d'oggi di solito si identifica con la rete urbana dei tram; ma esistono o sono esistite in passato realtà in cui non è o non era esattamente così.

Nel caso in questione credo si possa parlare di una metonìmia in cui viene scambiato il mezzo da prendere (il tram o altro materiale rotabile: si parla di cremagliera, il che mi fa pensare a un piccolo treno) con l'infrastruttura (la tranvia); sarebbe analogo dire "*prendo la ferrovia*" per indicare che mi sposto in treno.

Credo che al giorno d'oggi sia un'espressione considerata obsoleta, ed è molto più comune dire "*prendo il tram*".

Da notare però che viene utilizzata comunemente l'espressione "*prendere l'autostrada*".

Comment: Adesso mi sono ricordata che a Torino c'erano i tram, ma c'era anche la tranvia Sassi-Superga che era una cosa diversa perché si trattava di un veicolo a cremagliera che circolava su una collina.

Comment: Sempre riprendendo l'articolo di Wikipedia, si specifica che la differenza tra "tranvia" e "ferrovia" è labile, ed è principalmente che nella prima si va lenti in quanto si procede a vista. La linea di cui parli ricade in questa caratteristica?

Comment: Sono stata l'estate scorsa ed era così.

Comment: Quindi possiamo dire che è corretto che per "tranvia" si intenda una rete di trasporto locale (a livello di comune o provincia) a via guidata (di solito su binari) in cui, al contrario della ferrovia, si procede lentamente e a vista. Oggi si identifica con la rete urbana dei _tram_ ma ci sono o ci sono state in passato realtà in cui è o era diverso. Modificherò la mia risposta.

Comment: @charo ho modificato la mia risposta.

Comment: È curioso perché in catalano abbiamo il vocabolo "[tramvia](https://dlc.iec.cat/results.asp?txtEntrada=tramvia&operEntrada=0)" (e in castigliano "tranvía") che io avevo pensato si potesse sempre tradurre in italiano come "tram". Infatti, abbiamo anche il termine "[tram](http://mdlc.iec.cat/results.asp?txtEntrada=tram&operEntrada=0)", ma il dizionario afferma che si tratta semplicemente di una forma abbreviata del termine "tramvia". Potete anche vedere che i nostri dizionari non sono tanto buoni come quelli italiani :(.